# Qt Creator. Doxygen methods description doesn't show in pop up hints

Tags: linux, qt-creator, doxygen

I use **Qt Creator 10.0.1** based on Qt 6.2.4 (Red Hat 10.2.1-8.0.1) on my **Oracle Linux Server 8** OS. I have Doxygen plugin (I think so, because I can generate Doxygen method description just by writing `/*! + Enter key` above a method). **But** when I hover cursor on a method name I get only its return type, name and parameters hint.

I have Qt Creator 4.11.1 based on Qt 5.14.1 on my Windows 10 and there I can see the description.

What could be the problem?